# zsh: permission denied: /etc/hosts

Tags: port, hosts

While i try to intrude the port 80, i have to navigate to the host file located in /etc/hosts but as i enter the command /etc/hosts, it shows permission denied.

Firstly i wrote the command curl -I htttp://x.x.x.x
after that to access the backend server, my domain must be added to a list of trusted hosts but there i am facing this problem.

i was expecting to have the access to the website which displays nothing more than the most basic of information, but i didn't got the expected results.

Comment: You either need better instructions or to read the instructions you have more carefully. `/etc/hosts` isn't an executable; it's a text file. You need to open it in a text editor.